# how to using curl to export excel

Tags: curl

I am using curl to export excel like this:

```
 [miaoyou@MeowK8SSlave3 ~]$ curl https://10.244.6.75:11024/illidan-hub/report/game/export?startDateTime=2020-06-01%2000:00:00&endDateTime=2020-06-31%2023:59:59&tenantId=1&appIds=1 -o a.xls
[1] 2607
[2] 2608
[3] 2609
[2]-  Done                    endDateTime=2020-06-31%2023:59:59
[miaoyou@MeowK8SSlave3 ~]$ curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

what should I do to receive excel from curl?

Comment: Put the URL in quotes: you've got `&`s in there which your shell is interpreting as 'start a separate process', and so the curl command is only the part up to the first &. Why that would cause an SSL error though, I don't know - is the URL definitely correct?

Comment: I tweak the url and works,but result content is binary.@Rup

Comment: What doe `file a.xls` say - can it identify what you've got? If it's gzip or similar then maybe the server compressed it for transfer and curl didn't unpack that. But otherwise it's probably the binary data that the server is generating.